# How do I pass a command line argument while starting up GDB in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb, command-line-arguments

I have to debug a program that has errors in it as part of my assignment. However, I must first pass command line arguments in order to solve this problem.

I do:

```
gdb -tui InsertionSortWithErrors
```

which works, but after that I don't know how to pass arguments. I used `gdb -help` and it says something about `--args` which I also tried and it didn't work.

I want to be able to get the debugger+the GUIand pass command line arguments.

Answer (score 254, accepted):

Once `gdb` starts, you can run the program using "r *args*".

So if you are running your code by:

```
$ executablefile arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Debug it on `gdb` by:

```
$ gdb executablefile  
(gdb) r arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Comment: Just to expand on this....I am running mine normally like: `program --option1 --option2=argvalue` so in gdb I typed: `r --option1 --option2=argvalue`  This was not obvious to me at first.

Comment: This is rightly the top-voted comment. I'd just like to add that `r` stands for the gdb command `run`, and you can see a bit of help for it by typing `help run` while in gdb.

Comment: i don't want to have to type the arguments every time i start gdb, i want it in my command line history

Answer (score 128):

Try

```
gdb --args InsertionSortWithErrors arg1toinsort arg2toinsort
```

Comment: like mentioned in the GNU GDB Manual section [Invoking GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Invoking-GDB.html#Invoking-GDB)

Comment: It is also mentioned if you run `gdb -h`, which in turn is mentioned in the man page.

Comment: @PietroSaccardi there seems to be some discrepancy between the man page and the `-h` output, at least on some Ubuntu versions.  This can happen, especially if the man file file for a command is not updated as often as the source code that parses the `-h` option.

Answer (score 32):

I'm using GDB7.1.1, as `--help` shows:

```
gdb [options] --args executable-file [inferior-arguments ...]
```

IMHO, the order is a bit unintuitive at first.

Comment: I agree, very unintuitive, so the real commandline would read: `$ gdb --args <executable> <argument(s)>`. I mistakenly added quotes around everything after `--args` thing which lead caused gdb to parse the whole thing as the executable.

Comment: I think it's so the arguments come right after the executable, as if you were running without gdb.

Comment: What I think is unintutive is `--args`. If it was spelt `--run` it would be very intuitive

Answer (score 32):

Another option, once inside the GDB shell, before running the program, you can do

```
(gdb) set args file1 file2
```

and inspect it with:

```
(gdb) show args
```

Comment: This is the correct answer!