# how function visible to other functions in program?

Tags: c

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void) 
{
  int a=3,b=4;
  int c;
  c = max_min(a,b);
  printf("the max no is %d\n",c);
}
int max_min(int a,int b)
{
  if(a>b)
    return a;
  else if(b>a)
    return b;
}
```

> Error: 'max_min' was not declared in this scope
>         c = max_min(a,b);

Please help me out

Comment: This is an *extremely* Googleable error message. You could have gotten the answer much faster yourself, without wasting anyone else's time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function not declared in this scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327630/function-not-declared-in-this-scope) and hundreds of others

Comment: Possible duplicate of Function not declared in this scope and hundreds of others

Answer (score 2):

Either define you function before `main` or give a **forward declaration** of your function. Like this -

```
#include<stdio.h>
int max_min(int a,int b);       // forward declaration 
int main(void){
 // your code

}
// rest of code
```

You need to define or provide a forward declaration before using a function else compiler will throw an error as it does not see function definition or declaration till that point.

Answer (score 1):

Declare it. I.e. put `int max_min(int a,int b);` above `main`. This will tell the compiler about the function

i.e.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int max_min(int a,int b);

int main(void) 
{
  int a=3,b=4;
  int c;
  c = max_min(a,b);
  printf("the max no is %d\n",c);
}
int max_min(int a,int b)
{
  if(a>b)
    return a;
  else if(b>a)
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a prototype to tell the compiler that you have defined the function min_max later.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int max_min(int a,int b);

int main(void) 
{
 int a=3,b=4;
 int c;
 c = max_min(a,b);
 printf("the max no is %d\n",c);
 }
int max_min(int a,int b)
{
if(a>b)
return a;
else if(b>a)
 return b;
}
```

or define min_max before main

```
#include<stdio.h>

int max_min(int a,int b)
{
if(a>b)
return a;
else if(b>a)
 return b;
}

int main(void) 
{
 int a=3,b=4;
 int c;
 c = max_min(a,b);
 printf("the max no is %d\n",c);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a function prototype that declares the function, so the compiler knows what is being called from `main`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int max_min(int a,int b);       // function protoype

int main(void) 
{
    int a=3,b=4;
    int c;
    c = max_min(a,b);
    printf("the max no is %d\n",c);
}

int max_min(int a,int b)
{
    if(a>b)
        return a;
    else if(b>a)
        return b;
}
```

BTW the compiler should report "not all control paths return a value" since there is no value returned by the function when `a == b`.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to spend several days reading a book on Programming in C.

You also should look into websites like [C reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c).

In C, every function should have been declared (perhaps in some [included](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive) header) before being used.

So move your `max_min` function *before* your `main`, or declare it:

```
int max_min(int a,int b);
```

at declaration time, you don't need to name formals, so the following shorter declaration is possible:

```
int max_min(int,int);
```

BTW, `max_min` is really a poor and confusing name (since you don't compute the minimum, only the maximum). You mean `max` or perhaps `my_max` or `maximum`.

Don't forget to compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler). Then **use the debugger** (e.g. [GNU `gdb`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)). Perhaps a clever compiler would notice that you don't cover the case when `a` is equal to `b`.

You'll need to [test your program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing) for several inputs (and you could also use [formal methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_methods) to prove its correctness w.r.t. [specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_requirements_specification), e.g. with the help of [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/)). Instead of recompiling your code with various values for `a` and `b`, you might get them from the program arguments passed to `main` (converting them with [atoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi)), e.g.

```
int main(int argc, char**argv) {
   int a= 10;
   int b= 5;
   if (argc>1) 
     a = atoi(argv[1]);
   if (argc>2) 
     b = atoi(argv[2]);
   printf("a=%d b=%d\n", a, b);
```

etc....

Then you could run your program (in some terminal) with `./myprog 3 4` to test with `a` equal to 3 and `b` equal to 4. Actually you'll run that [in the debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14495000/841108) (e.g. `gdb --args ./myprog 3 4`).

BTW, you could also read (with [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)) the values of `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Try either one of it

First Declare the method before **Main method**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int max_min(int,int);
int main(void) 
{
  int a=3,b=4;
  int c;
  c = max_min(a,b);
  printf("the max no is %d\n",c);
}
int max_min(int a,int b)
{
  if(a>b)
   return a;
  else if(b>a)
   return b;
}
```

Or Specify the function before the main method

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int max_min(int a,int b)
{
  if(a>b)
   return a;
  else if(b>a)
   return b;
}
int main(void) 
{
  int a=3,b=4;
  int c;
  c = max_min(a,b);
  printf("the max no is %d\n",c);
}
```