# Error while compiling C program with gcc in VSCode

Tags: c

I wanted to compile the below code in VS Code, but I'm fetching this error using "code runner". I've looked up everywhere, but it didn't solve my issue.

I want to implement this `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + nlog(n)`

q2.c

```
// b. T(n) = 2T(n/2) + nlog(n)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int func(double n)
{
    return (2*func(n/2) + n*(log(n)));

}

int main()
{
    double n, result;
    printf("Enter the value of 'n' \n");
    scanf("%lf",&n);
    printf("Hey");
    result = func(n);
    printf("%lf \n",result);
    printf("Hey");

    return 0;

}
```

Console:

```
user@user-H310M-DS2:~/Desktop/C programming/Assignments$ cd "/home/user/Desktop/C programming/Assignments/" && gcc q2.c -o q2 && "/home/user/Desktop/C programming/Assignments/"q2
/tmp/ccnNXN3L.o: In function `func':
q2.c:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `log'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: How come you're using GCC as the compiler yet you claim that you're working with Visual Studio in the title?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "Visual Studio" and "VSCode" are two different things. First is an IDE (including compiler etc.), second is an extendible editor.

Comment: @Yunnosch: Oh!   That's confusing!  And that probably explains in part why Code Runner is mentioned, etc.  Oh well, I live, occasionally I learn (and the rest of the time my brain's too clogged with trivia to learn any more).  I hope I'll remember for next time.

Comment: Are you sure you want to call your function recursively without any limit? `return (func(n/2) + n*(log(n)));`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return (2*func(n/2) + n*(log(n)));`?

Comment: @pmg you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) has nothing to do with your issue, you are *not* compiling with it. Because it is an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) (or source code editor), not a compiler. I guess you are using it on some Linux or POSIX system. BTW my preferred [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) is GNU [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/). So your IDE is running some compilation commands (and you *need* to understand which ones and what these commands are doing). You could run these commands in a terminal (and that actually might be simpler).

As your console logs shows, you are compiling with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Some `gcc` command has been started (by Visual studio code probably).

Read carefully about [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html). Order of arguments matters a lot!

You should compile your code with

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g q2.c -lm -o q2
```

Let me explain this a bit:

- `gcc` is your compiler front-end (the actual compiler [is `cc1`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) but you never use it directly; you ask `gcc` to run it)
- `-Wall` asks for almost all warnings
- `-Wextra` asks for extra warnings. You'll be happy to get them
- `-g` asks for debugging information in [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF). You really want to be able to [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/), and `gdb` practically needs debugging information.
- `q2.c` is the source file of your sole [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))
- `-lm` is for your math library. You are using [log(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/log.3.html) and its documentation mention that.
- `-o q2` tells `gcc` to put the executable in `q2` (the actual work is done by the `ld` linker invoked by `gcc`)

How to configure visual studio code to use that command is your business. You could otherwise type the above command in a terminal. Then you can run your `q2` program by typing `./q2` in a terminal for your [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) (and you could use `gdb` [on it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14495000/841108)).

Notice that `gcc` is starting other programs (like `cc1`, `as`, `ld`). If you want to understand which ones, insert `-v` after `gcc` in the command above.

Be sure to read the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) of *every* function you are using (so read [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html), [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html), [log(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/log.3.html) at least...) and of every program you are using (e.g. [of `gcc`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/) and [of Visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs)).

Once you'll write bigger programs made of *several* translation units (e.g. `foo.c`, `bar.c`, `gee.c`), you would want to use some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (because compiling all of them every time with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g foo.c bar.c gee.c -lm -o qqq` is possible, but *inconvenient*). You could learn to use [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) (or [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/)).

Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Don't expect your program to work as you want at first.

BTW, study the source code of some *existing* [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) programs (but start with simple projects, e.g. on [github](http://github.com/), of less than a hundred thousand lines). This could teach you many useful things.

Comment: You could compile your code in a terminal. And you could run it in a terminal (or under a debugger)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how VSCode compiles programs, but since it uses GCC, it's likely that you need to link the math library `libm` when compiling, by supplying an argument `-lm` to GCC.

Answer (score 1):

Just a tweak to code runner's `settings.json` under `file`->`preferences`->`settings` of VS Code :

I've added the below line

```
"code-runner.executorMap": 
    {
        "c": "cd $dir && gcc -Wall -Wextra -g  $fileName -lm -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    }
```

It's working now.